# 3 columns in laravel referencing same table

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm putting together a project with an email system based solely in the app. Trying to do something that I'm not 100% sure can be done but didn't know a workaround. Basically, is there a way to have 3 columns in one table pull data from the same table elsewhere in the database? ie:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('email', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('user_id'); //for the 'to' field column
        $table->string('user_id'); //for the 'from' field column
        $table->string('user_id'); //for the 'Cc' field column
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Hope my explanation makes sense. Obviously, the user_id references users table

Comment: are user_id all going to be the same value?

Comment: In theory, no as people should be selecting different people per box

Comment: ok cool, why not call the columns something different? 'recipient_id' 'cc_id' and 'from_id' and then assign them the correct user id from your user table

Comment: if i add an answer will you accept it as i was first? ;)

Comment: Is that by using a foreign key?

Comment: yeah exactly that would be the User 'id' usually

Comment: Ok cool yeah happy to mark as first answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to give each column a unique name:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('email', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('user_to_id'); //for the 'to' field column
        $table->string('user_from_id'); //for the 'from' field column
        $table->string('user_cc_id'); //for the 'Cc' field column
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then within your EmailController.php when you were make a new email you would use something like:

```
public function store() 
{
    $email = new Email; // Email model
    $email->user_to_id = $request->recipient_input
    $email->user_from_id = $request->cc_input
    $email->user_cc_id = Auth::user()->id; // Guessing that the from id is from a logged in person
    $email->title = $request->title;
    $email->body = $request->body;
    $email->save();
}
```

Something along those lines :)

Comment: thanks man - let me know if you need any help - i've added a bit of example code for the controller

Comment: In your `store()` function, you wrote `user_to_id` thrice.

Comment: I highly recommend the use of Foreign Key Constraints as I wrote in my answer.
It helps strengthening the database consistency by forcing you to have the same data types. The foreign keys here are not supposed to be strings...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will have to give your columns distinct names:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('email', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('user_to_id'); //for the 'to' field column
        $table->string('user_from_id'); //for the 'from' field column
        $table->string('user_cc_id'); //for the 'Cc' field column
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

(I assume that your user table has string primary key and creating foreign keys as strings is deliberate)

Answer (score 0):

You can give these columns different names, then specify the references with  foreign key constraints.

In addition, since your `id` primary key in the `users` table is probably `increments('id')`, then you should put your `user_id_*` column as `unsignedInteger`.

---

**Migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('email', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id_to');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id_from');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id_cc');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id_to')
            ->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('user_id_from')
            ->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('user_id_cc')
            ->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

**Email Model**

```php
class Email extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'email';

    public function to()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id_to');
    }

    public function from()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id_from');
    }

    public function cc()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id_cc');
    }
}
```

See more in the [Laravel Database Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) documentation.

---

It's probably out of the scope of the question, but here are some improvements you can do:

- Make it possible to CC more than 1 user
- A mail body can generally be empty as well, so maybe can add `->nullable()`
- Same goes with your CCs, except if your requirements are saying so, your CCs should be nullable.